# Matching a word if preceding text is not "class=' "

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a regex for a search that will look at the following code and return only the ids and not the classes:

```
1   id="contact"
2   class="contact"
3   #contact
4   .contact
```

I want to return `contact` from the 1st and 3rd lines and NOT 2nd and 4th lines.

This is for a search across multiple files to avoid going through each one individually and checking whether it needs changing or not.

Is this possible?

Comment: On what basis are you rejecting 4th and selecting 3rd? Is this somewhere related to CSS?

Comment: I'm searching through lots of files looking for only contact IDs as opposed to contact classes so I just want to be able to select all of these and change them all at once in CODA. The IDs need changing because of a clash in a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
/(?:#|id=")(\w+)"?/g
```

strings beginning with either `#` or `id="` followed by word characters. You'll probably want to enhance it to handle dashes and underscores, I'd bet.

In this case, the first group is non-capturing, and the ID text will be your first capture group `$1`.

**UPDATE**

this one:

```
(?:(?<=id=")|(?<=#))(contact)
```

uses a positive lookbehind to find your prefixes and matches just the string "contact". This will NOT work in JavaScript (so you can't test it online) but will work in a text editor or CLI tool like `ack`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm trying to just return the 'contact' part but I still get '#contact' or 'id="contact"' with this. Is it possible to check for those yet exclude it from the results?

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding this? I tried testing it using this page: http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(%3F%3A%23%7Cid%3D%22)contact&input=id%3D%22contact%22%0Aclass%3D%22contact%22%0A%23contact%0A.contact - it selects the right lines but I only want the 'contact' part.